# flutter : Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a ListView inside a StatelessWidget. It has items and every item contains a checkbox. When someone checks an item, I want the ListView to send this as a parameter to another page. But when I do that, it's giving me this error:

```
I/flutter ( 7067): The following UnsupportedError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 7067): Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
I/flutter ( 7067): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

and this is my code

```
class StudentsList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Child> mList;
  StudentsList({this.mList});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Child> selectedList = [];

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 20),
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: mList == null ? 0 : mList.length,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (selectedList.isEmpty) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => SolokPage(
                      mChildList: [mList[position]],
                      isTeacher: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                if (!selectedList.contains(mList[position])) {
                  selectedList.add(mList[position]);
                }
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => SolokPage(
                      mChildList: selectedList,
                      isTeacher: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            child: StudentItem(
              student: mList[position],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Stateless Widget properties are meant to be immutable

```dart
class StudentsList extends StatelessWidget {
  // final means, flutter will not change value in future
  final List<Child> mList; 
  StudentsList({this.mList});
```

**Why ?**

Because **Flutter** expects **no business logic resides** in StatelessWidget.
If we need to add new Student in Student list, it is considered as business logic.
If we need to delete some Student in Student list, it is considered as business logic.

So by using stateless widget, Flutter will **only** focuses on How it will be displayed on Screen, what is the width, the constraints and etc.

That's why we found `final` syntaxes before class properties in `StatelessWidget`.

Similiar to our college life. Our *Grades* that marked in final report,  will not change even after we graduate from university. As it said to be in **Final Report**, then it must be **final**.

### Stateful Widget properties are mutable

**Why ?**
Because flutter expects **business logic resides** in StatefulWidget.

### Changes to be made

So I suggest to change StudentsList Widget, from this :

```dart
class StudentsList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Child> mList; // this is the issue
  StudentsList({this.mList});
```

to this one :

```dart
class StudentsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StudentsListState createState() => _StudentsListState();
}

class _StudentsListState extends State<StudentsList> {
  // final List<Child> mList; // Do not mark this as final

  List<Child> mList;

  ...

}
```

### Working Repository

You may look working repository that is closely-related to your issue. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_sqlist_list)

[image: Demo]

Comment: You only deleted the parameter of the widget but didn't answer the question.
The question was how to change a widget parameter which is final.
One possible answer would be to change the parameter to a callback function.

Comment: If you think your approach is good, please posted it as other answer. We can easily start discussing at the posted answer. I tried to help the author to get rid of the bug. If it was not suffice he could also put comment here, but he didn't. :)

Answer (score 0):

Stateless Widgets property cannot be immutable means in simple words is that it should not contain any non-final variables.

Simply convert it to Stateful widget and inside the `class _StudentsListState` create your variable WITHOUT the final keyword because you are modifying the value of that List.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep stateless (IE you just need to return some data or maybe youre using hooks) you could also try toList() to create a copy, then modify, then replace the original list

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in a simple function, and I solved it like this.

```
Future<void> createProduct({required Product product, required List<File> images}) async {
    for (final image in images) {
      final imageId = const Uuid().v4();

      final compressedimage = await ImageCompress.instance.compressFile(image);

      final taskSnapShot = await StorageService.instance.uploadProductPhoto(
        file: compressedimage,
        productId: product.productId,
        childUUID: imageId,
      );

      final downloadURL = await taskSnapShot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      product.imagesUrl.add(downloadURL);
      // sendProduct.addImages(downloadURL: downloadURL);
    }
    await _collection.doc().set(
          product.toMap(),
        );
  }
```

turn it into this.

```
  Future<void> createProduct({required Product product, required List<File> images})  
      async {
        List<String> newUrls = [];
        for (final image in images) {
          final imageId = const Uuid().v4();
    
          final compressedimage = await ImageCompress.instance.compressFile(image);
    
          final taskSnapShot = await StorageService.instance.uploadProductPhoto(
            file: compressedimage,
            productId: product.productId,
            childUUID: imageId,
          );
    
          final downloadURL = await taskSnapShot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          newUrls.add(downloadURL);
          // sendProduct.addImages(downloadURL: downloadURL);
        }
        final sendProduct = product.copyWith(imagesUrl: newUrls );
        await _collection.doc().set(
              sendProduct.toMap(),
            );
      }
```