# Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this unusual error while making my app. I am not exactly sure what it means to be honest. Also, It only does this error when I click on the checkbox for some reason. If you could please help me figure out what's wrong with the app that would be wonderful. Thank you.

> tasks_list.dart

```
class TasksList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TasksList({
    Key? key,
    required this.tasksList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List tasksList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      itemCount: tasksList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var task = tasksList[index];
        return TaskTile(task: task);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> task_tile.dart

```
class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const TaskTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.task,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Task task;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(width: 4),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                task.title,
                                maxLines: 3,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: const Color(0xFF89ABE3),
                                  fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
                                  fontSize: 19,
                                  decoration: task.isDone!
                                      ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                      : null,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                DateFormat().add_yMMMd().add_Hm().format(
                                      DateTime.parse(task.date),
                                    ),
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Color(0xFF89ABE3),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                PopupMenu(
                  favouriteCallback: () => context.read<TasksBloc>().add(
                        MakeFavouriteTask(task: task),
                      ),
                  task: task,
                ),
                Transform.scale(
                  scale: 1.2,
                  child: Checkbox(
                    shape: const CircleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    side: const BorderSide(
                      color: Color(0xFF89ABE3),
                    ),
                    activeColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                    value: task.isDone,
                    onChanged: task.isDeleted == false
                        ? (value) {
                            context
                                .read<TasksBloc>()
                                .add(UpdateTask(task: task));
                          }
                        : null,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 4),
        const Divider(
          thickness: 2,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

> Error Log

```
E/flutter (19323): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
E/flutter (19323): #0      UnmodifiableListMixin.insert (dart:_internal/list.dart:119:5)
E/flutter (19323): #1      TasksBloc._onUpdateTask (package:todo_list/blocs/tasks_bloc/tasks_bloc.dart:45:24)
E/flutter (19323): #2      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:226:26)
E/flutter (19323): #3      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:235:9)
E/flutter (19323): #4      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
E/flutter (19323): #5      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (19323): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:47)
E/flutter (19323): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #8      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #9      CastStreamSubscription._onData (dart:_internal/async_cast.dart:85:11)
E/flutter (19323): #10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:47)
E/flutter (19323): #11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #12     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (19323): #14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (19323): #15     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (19323): #16     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:195:12)
E/flutter (19323): #17     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (19323): #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:13)
E/flutter (19323): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #21     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (19323): #22     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
E/flutter (19323): #23     _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
E/flutter (19323): #24     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
E/flutter (19323): #25     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (19323): #26     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter (19323):
E/flutter (19323): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
E/flutter (19323): #0      UnmodifiableListMixin.insert (dart:_internal/list.dart:119:5)
E/flutter (19323): #1      TasksBloc._onUpdateTask (package:todo_list/blocs/tasks_bloc/tasks_bloc.dart:45:24)
E/flutter (19323): #2      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:226:26)
E/flutter (19323): #3      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:235:9)
E/flutter (19323): #4      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
E/flutter (19323): #5      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (19323): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:47)
E/flutter (19323): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #8      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #9      CastStreamSubscription._onData (dart:_internal/async_cast.dart:85:11)
E/flutter (19323): #10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:47)
E/flutter (19323): #11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #12     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (19323): #14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (19323): #15     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (19323): #16     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:195:12)
E/flutter (19323): #17     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (19323): #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:13)
E/flutter (19323): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #21     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (19323): #22     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
E/flutter (19323): #23     _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
E/flutter (19323): #24     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
E/flutter (19323): #25     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (19323): #26     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter (19323):
E/flutter (19323): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
E/flutter (19323): #0      UnmodifiableListMixin.insert (dart:_internal/list.dart:119:5)
E/flutter (19323): #1      TasksBloc._onUpdateTask (package:todo_list/blocs/tasks_bloc/tasks_bloc.dart:45:24)
E/flutter (19323): #2      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:226:26)
E/flutter (19323): #3      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:235:9)
E/flutter (19323): #4      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
E/flutter (19323): #5      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (19323): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:47)
E/flutter (19323): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #8      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #9      CastStreamSubscription._onData (dart:_internal/async_cast.dart:85:11)
E/flutter (19323): #10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:47)
E/flutter (19323): #11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #12     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (19323): #14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (19323): #15     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (19323): #16     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:195:12)
E/flutter (19323): #17     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (19323): #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:13)
E/flutter (19323): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
E/flutter (19323): #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
E/flutter (19323): #21     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (19323): #22     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
E/flutter (19323): #23     _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
E/flutter (19323): #24     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
E/flutter (19323): #25     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (19323): #26     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

> tasks_bloc.dart

```
class TasksBloc extends HydratedBloc<TasksEvent, TasksState> {
  TasksBloc() : super(const TasksState()) {
    on<AddTask>(_onAddTask);
    on<UpdateTask>(_onUpdateTask);
    on<RemoveTask>(_onRemoveTask);
    on<DeleteTask>(_onDeleteTask);
    on<MakeFavouriteTask>(_onMakeFavouriteTask);
    on<EditTask>(_onEditTask);
    on<RestoreTask>(_onRestoreTask);
    on<DeleteAllTasks>(_onDeleteAllTasks);
  }

  void _onAddTask(AddTask event, Emitter<TasksState> emitter) {
    final state = this.state;
    emitter(
      TasksState(
        pendingTasks: List.from(state.pendingTasks)..add(event.task),
        completedTasks: state.completedTasks,
        favouriteTasks: state.favouriteTasks,
        deletedTasks: state.deletedTasks,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onUpdateTask(UpdateTask event, Emitter<TasksState> emit) {
    final state = this.state;
    final task = event.task;

    List<Task> pendingTasks = state.pendingTasks;
    List<Task> completedTasks = state.completedTasks;
    List<Task> favouriteTasks = state.favouriteTasks;

    if (task.isDone == false) {
      if (task.isFavourite == false) {
        pendingTasks = List.from(pendingTasks)..remove(task);
        completedTasks.insert(0, task.copyWith(isDone: true));
      } else {
        var taskIndex = favouriteTasks.indexOf(task);
        pendingTasks = List.from(pendingTasks)..remove(task);
        completedTasks.insert(0, task.copyWith(isDone: true));
        favouriteTasks = List.from(favouriteTasks)
          ..remove(task)
          ..insert(taskIndex, task.copyWith(isDone: true));
      }
    } else {
      if (task.isFavourite == false) {
        completedTasks = List.from(completedTasks)..remove(task);
        pendingTasks = List.from(pendingTasks)
          ..insert(0, task.copyWith(isDone: false));
      } else {
        var taskIndex = favouriteTasks.indexOf(task);
        completedTasks = List.from(completedTasks)..remove(task);
        pendingTasks = List.from(pendingTasks)
          ..insert(0, task.copyWith(isDone: false));
        favouriteTasks = List.from(favouriteTasks)
          ..remove(task)
          ..insert(taskIndex, task.copyWith(isDone: false));
      }
    }
    emit(TasksState(
      pendingTasks: pendingTasks,
      completedTasks: completedTasks,
      favouriteTasks: favouriteTasks,
      deletedTasks: state.deletedTasks,
    ));
  }

  void _onRemoveTask(RemoveTask event, Emitter<TasksState> emitter) {
    final state = this.state;
    emitter(
      TasksState(
        pendingTasks: state.pendingTasks,
        completedTasks: state.completedTasks,
        favouriteTasks: state.favouriteTasks,
        deletedTasks: List.from(state.deletedTasks)..remove(event.task),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onDeleteTask(DeleteTask event, Emitter<TasksState> emitter) {
    final state = this.state;
    emitter(
      TasksState(
        pendingTasks: List.from(state.pendingTasks)..remove(event.task),
        completedTasks: List.from(state.completedTasks)..remove(event.task),
        favouriteTasks: List.from(state.favouriteTasks)..remove(event.task),
        deletedTasks: List.from(state.deletedTasks)
          ..add(
            event.task.copyWith(isDeleted: true),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onMakeFavouriteTask(
      MakeFavouriteTask event, Emitter<TasksState> emitter) {
    final state = this.state;
    List<Task> pendingTasks = state.pendingTasks;
    List<Task> completedTasks = state.completedTasks;
    List<Task> favouriteTasks = state.favouriteTasks;
    if (event.task.isDone == false) {
      if (event.task.isFavourite == false) {
        var taskIndex = pendingTasks.indexOf(event.task);
        pendingTasks = List.from(pendingTasks)
          ..remove(event.task)
          ..insert(
            taskIndex,
            event.task.copyWith(isFavourite: true),
          );
        favouriteTasks.insert(0, event.task.copyWith(isFavourite: true));
      } else {
        var taskIndex = pendingTasks.indexOf(event.task);
        pendingTasks = List.from(pendingTasks)
          ..remove(event.task)
          ..insert(
            taskIndex,
            event.task.copyWith(isFavourite: false),
          );
        favouriteTasks.remove(event.task);
      }
    } else {
      if (event.task.isFavourite == false) {
        var taskIndex = completedTasks.indexOf(event.task);
        completedTasks = List.from(completedTasks)
          ..remove(event.task)
          ..insert(
            taskIndex,
            event.task.copyWith(isFavourite: true),
          );
        favouriteTasks.insert(
          0,
          event.task.copyWith(isFavourite: true),
        );
      } else {
        var taskIndex = completedTasks.indexOf(event.task);
        completedTasks = List.from(completedTasks)
          ..remove(event.task)
          ..insert(
            taskIndex,
            event.task.copyWith(isFavourite: false),
          );
        favouriteTasks.remove(event.task);
      }
    }
    emitter(
      TasksState(
          pendingTasks: pendingTasks,
          completedTasks: completedTasks,
          favouriteTasks: favouriteTasks,
          deletedTasks: state.deletedTasks),
    );
  }

  void _onEditTask(EditTask event, Emitter<TasksState> emitter) {
    final state = this.state;
    List<Task> favouriteTasks = state.favouriteTasks;
    if (event.oldTask.isFavourite == true) {
      favouriteTasks
        ..remove(event.oldTask)
        ..insert(
          0,
          event.currentTask,
        );
    }
    emitter(
      TasksState(
        pendingTasks: List.from(state.pendingTasks)
          ..remove(event.oldTask)
          ..insert(0, event.currentTask),
        completedTasks: state.completedTasks..remove(event.oldTask),
        favouriteTasks: state.favouriteTasks,
        deletedTasks: state.deletedTasks,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onRestoreTask(RestoreTask event, Emitter<TasksState> emitter) {
    final state = this.state;
    emitter(
      TasksState(
        deletedTasks: List.from(state.deletedTasks)..remove(event.task),
        pendingTasks: List.from(state.pendingTasks)
          ..insert(
            0,
            event.task
                .copyWith(isDeleted: false, isDone: false, isFavourite: false),
          ),
        completedTasks: state.completedTasks,
        favouriteTasks: state.favouriteTasks,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onDeleteAllTasks(DeleteAllTasks event, Emitter<TasksState> emitter) {
    final state = this.state;
    emitter(TasksState(
      deletedTasks: List.from(state.deletedTasks)..clear(),
      pendingTasks: state.pendingTasks,
      completedTasks: state.completedTasks,
      favouriteTasks: state.favouriteTasks,
    ));
  }

  @override
  TasksState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TasksState.fromMap(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(TasksState state) {
    return state.toMap();
  }
}
```

Comment: could you include TasksBloc class too?

Comment: @eamirho3ein yes ofc.

Comment: Try changing `completedTasks.insert(0, task.copyWith(isDone: true))` to `completedTasks = List.from(completedTasks)..insert(0, task.copyWith(isDone: true))`

Comment: why you use `StatelessWidget` ? Change it to `StatefulWidget` instead. You may refer this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553883/5156075 .

Comment: @JohnJoe I just changed it. And I used StatelessWidget because I am not using a setState here so yeah. (I am still a beginner in flutter).

Answer (score 1):

```
class TasksList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TasksList({
    Key? key,
    required this.tasksList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List tasksList;
```

This `tasksList` is unmodifiable.

WHat you'd want to do is listen/get new data from the bloc
using `context.watch<TasksBloc>().completedTasks`

e.g

Sample usage.

```
class TasksList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TasksList({
    Key? key,
    
  }) : super(key: key);

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final  tasksList =context.watch<TasksBloc>().completedTasks;

    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      itemCount: tasksList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var task = tasksList[index];
        return TaskTile(task: task);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where should I write that? griffins

Comment: thank you griffins, I will try that also